# Error while checking if ID exists in database file

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datareader

I am trying to check if certain ID already exists in database. When it doesn't, I want user to change the id to something else.

All this is done in `TextChanged` function of textobx.

The problem is that I am getting an error, and since query looks good I am not sure why i see this: `The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.`

Method which does the check:

```
private bool DoesIDExist(int dataID, string filePath)
{
    HashPhrase hash = new HashPhrase();
    DataTable temp = new DataTable();

    string hashShortPass = hash.ShortHash(pass);
    bool result = false;

    // Creating a connection string. Using placeholders make code
    // easier to understand.
    string connectionString =
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};
          Persist Security Info=False; Jet OLEDB:Database Password={1};";

    string sql = string.Format
        ("SELECT FROM PersonalData WHERE [DataID] = {0}", dataID);

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        // Creating command object.
        // Using a string formatting let me to insert data into
        // place holders I have used earlier.
        connection.ConnectionString =
            string.Format(connectionString, filePath, hashShortPass);

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            // Creating command object.
            // Using a string formatting let me to insert data into
            // place holders I have used earlier.
            connection.ConnectionString =
                string.Format(connectionString, filePath, hashShortPass);

            try
            {
                // Open database connection.
                connection.Open();

                using (OleDbDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // Checking if there is any data in the file.
                    if (read.HasRows)
                    {
                        // Reading information from the file.
                        while (read.Read())
                        {
                            if (read.GetInt32(0) == dataID)
                                return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your select is missing some columns you want to extract out??

```
string sql = string.Format
    ("SELECT FROM PersonalData WHERE [DataID] = {0}", dataID);
```

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
string sql = string.Format
    ("SELECT * FROM PersonalData WHERE [DataID] = {0}", dataID);
```

Comment: Lol. Genius people always miss minor stuff :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify something in the `SELECT` clause. I guess:

```
SELECT DataID FROM PersonalData WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing what to select

```
string sql = string.Format
    ("SELECT FROM PersonalData WHERE [DataID] = {0}", dataID);
```

Change to something like

```
string sql = string.Format
    ("SELECT * FROM PersonalData WHERE [DataID] = {0}", dataID);
```

And: you're open to SQL-Injection the way you build your query.

Comment: Yes. I am just trying to make that work. Now I will work on using parameters. But, since I am checking field for empty field, non number characters, or non-existing IDs I believe I am safe as it is. Program is kind of simple :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line of code:

```
string sql = string.Format
        ("SELECT FROM PersonalData WHERE [DataID] = {0}", dataID);
```

You need to specify what you want to select. Example: `SELECT *`, `SELECT [MyColumn]`, `SELECT TOP 1 *`, etc. Based on your requirements, something like seems to be what you're looking for:

```
string sql = string.Format
 ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS UserCount FROM PersonalData WHERE [DataID] = {0}", dataID);
```

**Additional Information:**

If this method is being used on the web, say pulling in an ID from the query string, then you're leaving yourself open to **SQL injection attack**. Slightly modifiying your code would fix the problem:

```
string sql = "SELECT FROM PersonalData WHERE [DataID] = @DataID";

using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataID", dataID);
        }
```

Comment: @HelpNeeder, Great! Unfortunately, many people aren't. I try to be verbose in my answer for archiving purposes. In addition, well thought out answers *typically* receive more upvotes :)